# Wired xbox controller not working with LG G2

Tags: usb-on-the-go, game-controllers, lg-g2

My boyfriend purchased a USB OTG cable so he can play Android games with an Xbox 360 wired controller.  When he plugs the Xbox controller into his LG G2 nothing happens, I plugged it into my Samsung Galaxy S4 and it worked  immediately. His LG G2 recognizes a flash drive, keyboard and mouse right away so we know the cable is working just fine. What could be causing the Xbox controller to not work?

The AT&T LG G2 is rooted running 4.2.2 with stock ROM.  The Keylayout file `vendor_045e_product.028e.kl` used for the Xbox 360 wired controller was already on the phone.  Running the app titled "USB Device Info" with the Xbox 360 wired controller plugged in shows the controllers info in both the Android and Linux tabs.  The device seems to recognize everything it's supposed to but won't work with any games or emulators.  It wont even allow the controller to navigate the home screen.

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem with my Galaxy s3 rooted stock rom. It appears to me that the system doesn't load the driver for the Xbox controller to recognize it when plugged in. However, the app bt/usb joystick center is able to recognize and read inputs from the device. I don't know how to get the system to read those inputs however. My motive for posting this is to see if anyone has found a solution perhaps using the terminal emulator app to manually load the driver... I don't understand enough about system drivers to try this myself. Another thought I've had is if my device has the

Comment: (continuing FPSHero's comment) ...wrong key layout file is it different for each device? I have prod_0291.kl(possibly for nexus 7?) prod_0791.kcm(wireless) and apparently prod_028e.kl and I have edited their permissions to read, as is with the other keylayout files, but the system just doesn't call the file when the device is plugged in. Interestingly it recognizes keyboards usb drives etc without root access or editing system files etc.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not have the final solution - I was able to make some progress in figuring out why the G2 fails to work with the 360 controller.

I've been doing diagnostics and noticed that the LG G2 USB connection manager is emulating a USB2.0 and USB3.0 device hub - which shows up when an OTG cable is connected to the phone - and while it identifies the 360 controller, its non-standard integration is likely causing the device to not be recognized by applications.

Using USB/BT Joystick Center from the play store, I was able to refuse permission to access the USB Hub devices, but permit the app to talk to the Xbox controller. (When it scans for devices, it will display "FOUND: *Device Name*" then prompt for permission. When it displays "FOUND: Xbox 360 Controller" approve access. Deny all other prompts, or else the software cannot communicate with the controller).

Immediately after doing the above, the controller's LEDs stopped flashing - and locked into 'Player 1' configuration. Then the software loaded a default 360 profile, and clicking on driver let me see the raw inputs from the controller. It works!

It seems to me that the device is perfectly compatible, but the LG OTG input manager is doing something funky with the input - and needs another piece of software to channel the inputs from the USB device to the system. If there were a way to get the LG software to identify it as a keyboard or gamepad, that would be ideal.

I'll keep working at it for now.